# error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'string'

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

this is probably an include problem, i get these errors all over the code, and not only for string identifier for example `error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'getName'` and `error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'name'`

here's an example class:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

class participant
{
public:
participant(int id, string name);
~participant(void);

int getId();
string getName();

private:
        int id;
    string name;
};
```

here's my `stdafx.h` file:

```
#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include "day.h"
#include "appointment.h"
#include "extendedAppointment.h"
#include "participant.h"
#include "calendar.h"
using namespace std;

#define no_such_appointment_error 20;
#define conflicting_appointments_error 21;
#define noSuchDayError 22;
#define incorrectAppointmentError 23;
```

Comment: `using` a namespace in a header file is a terrible idea.  Any file that includes your header now has `using namespace std;` in it (this is bad).

Comment: thanks, removed it. still not fixed

Comment: It's not directly shown to be a problem in the code you posted, since what you've posted doesn't show them being used, but macros that end in a semi-colon are nearly always going to cause problems.

Comment: You shouldn't write `;` in your `#define`s. But I think it's not what cause your problem.

Comment: @MichaelBurr: Well if you remove that then `string` immediately becomes undefined (use `std::string` instead).  Furthermore, why are your `#define`s ended with semi-colons?

Comment: Holy mother, you probably don't want to include everything in `stdafx.h` and you certainly don't want to have `using namespace std;` anywhere and you definitely don't put semicolons after `#define` if you even needed them.

Comment: i've removed the semicolons thanks for noticing. still, something else is wrong and i don't understand what

Comment: name your errors consistently..

Comment: @AJG85 Why not include everything in `stdafx.h` ? this way i put all the includes in one file and don't have to worry about dependencies. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Michael because `stdafx.h` is for your precompiled header file. It's included everywhere so you only want to put things in it that are needed everywhere and do not change often. If you put everything in `stdafx.h` anytime you change one of your headers you must recompile your entire project instead of just the bit that changed. A general rule of thumb is to include as few headers in headers as possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So I compiled your code as-posted without your custom header files and it worked just fine.  Based on that, I am going to wager that you have a problem in one of these header files:

```
#include "day.h"
#include "appointment.h"
#include "extendedAppointment.h"
#include "participant.h"
#include "calendar.h"
```

It could be a macro, a class/struct not terminated with a semi-colon, etc.  Check those out.

Lastly, a few of tangential issues:

First, `using` a namespace in a header file is a terrible idea. Any file that includes your header now has `using namespace std;` in it (this is bad).  You probably don't want to include that many header files in every file that includes `stdafx.h`.

Secondly,  once you remove that then `string` immediately becomes undefined (use std::string instead).

Last, why are your `#define`s ended with semi-colons?  No need for that.

Comment: `targetver.h` is generated by Visual Studio so we can probably assume it's not the culprit as well.

Comment: I see. thanks, i will start eliminating all the possibilities

Comment: @EdS. about `string` should i just replace each occurrence of `string` with `std::string` ? thats a lot of `std::string` to write. isn't there a better way ?

Comment: You can do a `using std::string;` which is slightly better than pulling in the entire namespace but most people prefer to use explicit scoping like `std::string` to avoid naming conflicts and for clarity.

Comment: @AJG85: It would be better, but I would never do it in a header file.

Comment: @Ed S. Correct, I wouldn't either. I was just mentioning the alternative.